# 2.8 Touchscreen does not work with Proto Screw Shield

Tags: spi, display, tft

I am using the Arduino Mega and the 2.8 touch screen by Adafruit, and I can't get the screen to work on my Proto R3 Screw Shield

Here are the tools I am using:

- [2.8 inch touch screen](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-2-8-tft-touch-shield-v2/overview)
- [Proto R3 Screw Shield](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-proto-screw-shield/intro)

When I put the touch screen onto the Arduino Mega, no wiring needed, and run the graphic test [provided by the Adafruit_ILI9341](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-2-8-tft-touch-shield-v2/graphics-test), everything works perfectly. The touch screen runs the animation, and my serial monitor outputs the information of my touch screen.

However, when I put the touch screen on the screw shield, which I place on the Arduino Mega, **the touch screen stays white**, no matter if I press either reset button, unplug and replug the Arduino, restart the IDE, take off and put everything back on.

I explicitly followed the instructions by Adafruit [here](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-proto-screw-shield/solder-it) that say how to get the screw shield working.

There is no contact between each soldered pin, and I cut and soldered the ICSP and MEGA jumpers on the bottom of the touch screen accordingly, as shown in the picture on the bottom right:

[image]

I tried using an SD card as a test to see if the proto R3 screw shield was not working at all, and reading an image off of the SD card. I got **proper, working results**, so everything worked fine with the screw shield then. This means that the screw shield still works with it's 5V pin.

What could be the cause of the touchscreen staying white? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are set to use the ICSP header for communication with the screen. That is good, when you are directly connected to a Mega.

However that is bad when you are going via a shield that *doesn't have an ICSP header*.

The ICSP header is the 6-pin (3x2) header in the right of your picture. It has SPI signals that the screen needs. Your screw shield lacks those pins.

You need to pass those signals through. The simplest way would be to add a 3x2 stackable header (or two 3x1 stackable headers) upside down through the correct holes to line up with the ICSP header.